# What is the type of motion system of the Ender 5 called?

Tags: creality-ender-5, creality

It's not CoreXY, it's not H-Bot and it's definitly not a bedslinger. What do you call this type of motion system?

Answer (score 1):

It's a plain cartesian motion system that's basically the same as an Ender 3/bedslinger, except that the X gantry moves along the Y axis rather than the Z, and is driven by belt rather than lead screw. So far this is pretty much identical to an Ender 3 with belt-driven Z mod, just rotated 90 degrees. I'm not sure there's any particular name for it. Cartesian motion systems have lots of variations for the specifics of how each axis moves, and most don't seem to have dedicated names unless there's a reason to talk about good or bad properties of a whole class (as is the case with bedslingers).

Comment: "z-bed rectilinear cartesian"?